# S21 & S12 of a mismatched transmission line

Tags: transmission-line, microwave, s-parameters

I am trying to solve this problem:

[image]

Since it is asking for a reference impedance of 50 Ω there will be a mismatch, and hence reflections at the Port 1 for calculation of S12.

I already know S11 and S22 to be 0.6, since the electrical length is a quarter-wave transformer, hence it is straightforward to compute Z<sub>in</sub> which turns out to be 200 Ω, and hence the input reflection coefficient γ to be 0.6.

Now, I need to write V1 and V2 in terms of {V1+, V1-} and  {V2+, V2-} respectively, but I am completely lost. Any direction that I should take will be greatly appreciated.

Here is my wrong solution. Can someone guide me in the right direction? Is
the derivations of V1+, V1-, V2+ and V2- correct?

[image]

Comment: Where's V1 and where's V2 located? Best to be explicit. Why are you trying to rewrite them? What are you aiming to achieve?

Comment: Well, I was trying to derive the S12 parameter of the network. I have attached my solution, it's not right! The correct answer should be 0.8.

Answer (score 1):

Since the network is lossless the sum of the transmission coefficient squared and the reflection coefficient squared has to be equal to 1. With this, you get S12 and S21 equal to 0.8.